# Difference between git pull and git pull origin master

Tags: git, github

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
git pull
```

and

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Edit, May 2018: `git pull` is no longer a shell script and a few details are different in modern Git.  Pull also now has recursion options that make it more useful with submodules.  This answer ignores the submodules.]

The `git pull` script is meant as a convenience method for invoking `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, with `git pull --rebase`, invoking `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`).

The first extra argument to `git pull` tells it which remote to give to the `fetch` operation:

```
git pull origin
```

for example, means to fetch from `origin`.  If you leave this out, Git uses the current branch's `remote`:

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
origin
```

The second (and any additional) arguments to `git pull` tell it which branch or branches to merge in.  These are the names of the branches as found on the remote.  For instance, suppose you create a new branch `feature2` that tracks `origin/feature`:

```
$ git checkout -b feature2 origin/feature
```

If you now want to fetch from `origin` to pick up new commits added to their `feature` branch, but merge them in to your local `feature2` branch:

```
$ git pull origin feature
```

If you leave out the branch name(s), git uses the current branch's `merge`:

```
$ git config --get branch.feature2.merge
feature
```

Note that if you list multiple branch names, Git will do an "octopus merge".  In my experience, this usually surprises people the first time: they think `git pull remote br1 br2` will run `git fetch` followed by a series of separate `git merge`-s on each branch, but that's not what happens.

Comment: as always awesome explanation. But in the recent version I see `git pull origin` updates all the remote tracking branches ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: that's certainly possible, if someone decided that `git pull origin` should run `git fetch origin` rather than `git fetch origin <branch>`. Now that `git pull` is written in C rather than shell script it's harder to inspect its interior details, and Git is always evolving. From a quick scan of the source, it appears now that `git pull origin` runs `git fetch origin`, which will fetch everything. I'll update this answer (which is from 2014).

Answer (score 21):

`git pull origin master` will pull changes from the origin remote, master branch and merge them to the local checked-out branch.

where as `git pull` will fetch new commits from all tracked branches from the default remote(origin). you can also configure default remote and branch name in `gitconfig` file.

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

This will add the following info to your `gitconfig` file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

now whenever you say `git pull` it will fetch from origin master.

Comment: `--set-upstream`  does not work anymore. Use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master`

Answer (score 9):

`git pull origin master` is the verbose form which specifies both the remote (`origin`) and the branch to pull from (`master`). If you don’t specify that, Git will apply a default behavior that is explained [in the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_default_behaviour):

> Often people use `git pull` without giving any parameter. Traditionally, this has been equivalent to saying `git pull origin`. However, when configuration `branch.<name>.remote` is present while on branch `<name>`, that value is used instead of origin.
>
> […]
>
> In order to determine what remote branches to fetch (and optionally store in the remote-tracking branches) when the command is run without any refspec parameters on the command line, values of the configuration variable `remote.<origin>.fetch` are consulted, and if there aren't any, `$GIT_DIR/remotes/<origin>` file is consulted and its `Pull:` lines are used.